# Why has the original snackbar behavior changed and how can it be restored?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

The snackbar in the first gif was created with the original `Snackbar.make(view, "This is a snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()` and pops up from the bottom of the screen. The snackbar in the second image was created with Compose and `SnackbarHost` and appears from the middle.

Why was this behavior changed and is there a way to restore the original behavior while using `SnackbarHost`?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the current code of `SnackbarHost` and `Snackbar` currently it's not possible to change the style to the older one for snackbar.

This is because each style of snackbar is built with different components.

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalTextStyle provides textStyle) {
    when {
        action == null -> OneRowSnackbar(
            text = content,
            action = null,
            dismissAction = dismissAction,
            actionTextStyle,
            actionContentColor,
            dismissActionContentColor
        )
        actionOnNewLine -> NewLineButtonSnackbar(
            content,
            action,
            dismissAction,
            actionTextStyle,
            actionContentColor,
            dismissActionContentColor
        )
        else -> OneRowSnackbar(
            text = content,
            action = action,
            dismissAction = dismissAction,
            actionTextStyle,
            actionContentColor,
            dismissActionContentColor
        )
    }
}
```

Also, the `SnackbarVerticalPadding` field, which I believe is used to define the padding from the parent's borders, is set to private.

```
private val SnackbarVerticalPadding = 6.dp
```

There is also no way to change the animation for Snackbar which is `FadeInFadeOutWithScale` because it is hard coded.

```
@Composable
fun SnackbarHost(
    hostState: SnackbarHostState,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    snackbar: @Composable (SnackbarData) -> Unit = { Snackbar(it) }
) {
    val currentSnackbarData = hostState.currentSnackbarData
    val accessibilityManager = LocalAccessibilityManager.current
    LaunchedEffect(currentSnackbarData) {
        if (currentSnackbarData != null) {
            val duration = currentSnackbarData.visuals.duration.toMillis(
                currentSnackbarData.visuals.actionLabel != null,
                accessibilityManager
            )
            delay(duration)
            currentSnackbarData.dismiss()
        }
    }
    FadeInFadeOutWithScale(
        current = hostState.currentSnackbarData,
        modifier = modifier,
        content = snackbar
    )
}
```